# The width of columns in a table change when a row of input boxes is added dinamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

[The table before the row with input-boxes is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PXOn.png)
As you see in the image above, there is a table that contains on the first row, a button for showing/hiding  the row that contains input-boxes like in the image below.

[The table where the row with input boxes is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJyXb.png)
The problem is that the width of the columns is changed when the row that contains input-boxes is displayed. (It can be seen from the images the difference of width's columns, before and after)
And the width of the input-boxes is set to 100%.
Also the padding and border are not changed, only the width of td.
So the question is, how can I mentain the same width of the columns, without setting a fixed width, like in the code below?

```
td { width: 50px;}
```

And also adding

```
white-space: nowrap
```

doesn't work!

Here is the part of the code for showing the row with the input-boxes.

```
<tr v-if="showFilters">
    <td v-for="key in filterKeys" v-if="key.visible">
        <div class="input-group">
          <pf-text-field v-model="key.value" tooltip="Filter"> </pf-text-field>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using flex properties ?

```
td {
 display : flex;
}
```

Theoretically, the default size should be 100% for a lone child... You can add padding and it will adapt!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't tell the browser the prefered size of table cells, it will try to adjust the widths proportionally based on the width of the widest table cells in each column. These are your table cells with the input fields, as soon as they are shown (they are having width: 100%)

I assume you simply want some columns to be smaller than others, as they hold smaller data. You could use %-based width for this. Optionally min-width or max-width might be useful as well, in case your site is responsive and some minimum width should always be kept. E.g.

```
td {
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

Hint: Using a different table-layout might prevent some weird behavior in case some cells get too large:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```